# Pulling numbers out of a bag without replacement, probability of pulling a certain sum?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I want to sample without replacement by pulling numbers out of a bag. I want to know the probability of pulling $k$ numbers and having their sum either be equal to, or greater than some value.

This would be directly countable with a small amount of numbers in the bag, but what if there's too many to count?

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389140/odds-of-choosing-items-out-of-a-bag) it seems that using Stirling numbers, or something similarly appropriate, would be useful here. But how can I do this without replacement?

In case a direct example is useful:
In a bag of 107 numbers there's:
80 0's,
21 1's,
5 3's,
and one 7.

After pulling 10 numbers without replacement, what is the probability of getting a sum equal to 6? Greater than 6?

Comment: Stirling numbers are useful in the linked question because it is an occupancy/coupon collector's problem.  Here I would suggest simulation

Comment: @Henry I'd actually wanted to take up this approach because resampling was too slow computationally, due to the number of these problems I want to solve. I thought a direct calculation might be cleaner. This definitely gives me a new dilemma.

Comment: Estif, you said that there are 20k to 100k numbers in the bag. How many distinct numbers are there, and how many are you drawing?

Comment: @RobertDodier It varies by problem, I have multitudes of these bags. Those are the general ranges that can be expected.

Comment: It will help others help you if you can say, in addition to how many numbers are in a bag, how many are distinct and how many you're drawing; that info might make some approximations more appealing. For example, if the number you are drawing is much smaller than the number of items in the bag, then assuming replacement could be a simpler, workable approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup for general case.

Let it be that the bag contains $r_i$ numbers $i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,m$ and let $r=\sum_{i=0}^mr_i$.

If you want to calculate the probability on a sum $s$ by pulling $k$ numbers then let $T\subseteq\mathbb N^{m+1}$ be the set of tuples $(n_0,n_1,\dots,n_m)$ that satisfy:

- $n_i\leq r_i$ for every $i$.
- $\sum_{i=0}^mn_i=k$
- $\sum_{i=0}^min_i=s$

Then the probability is:$$\sum_{(n_0,\dots,n_m)\in T}\frac{\binom{r_0}{n_0}\times\cdots\times\binom{r_m}{n_m}}{\binom{r}{k}}$$

---

This is precise and can be applied to solve the example you mentioned, but will be soon unmanageable in "larger" cases. So actually gives you no answer if "there is too many to count".

Comment: There is a lot of difficulty hidden in $T$

Comment: @Henry Indeed. I don't think this is of much use and cannot find a natural approximation. If there is one then I will be surprised.

Comment: So how large is large? To add some context, The problems I'm looking to solve would deal in the order of ~20,000-100,000 numbers in the bag.Would this give an inaccurate answer?

Comment: In principle the answer would be *precise* (as I said). So that is not the point. The determination of $T$ is difficult though.